# Get always margin 1cm top and left on ZEBRA Printing

Tags: c#, itext, zebra-printers

i print pdf to my ZEBRA printer. the ZEBRA paper size is 10cm x 7Cm. i got always as a gap of 1 cm.! 
[image]

how can i get rid off this gap ?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // step 1
    // need to write to memory first due to IE wanting
    // to know the length of the pdf beforehand
    MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();

    Rectangle pageSize = new Rectangle(100f, 70f) ;

    pageSize.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK;
    pageSize.BorderWidth = 4f;
    pageSize.BorderWidthBottom = 2f;

    Document document = new Document(pageSize, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
    try
    {
        // step 2: we set the ContentType and create an instance of the Writer
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, m);
        writer.CloseStream = false;

        // step 3
        document.Open();

        // step 4
       document.Add(new Paragraph("This is a custom size"));
    }
    catch (DocumentException ex)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    // step 5: Close document
    document.Close();

    // step 6: Write pdf bytes to outputstream
    Response.OutputStream.Write(m.GetBuffer(), 0, m.GetBuffer().Length);
    Response.OutputStream.Flush();
    Response.OutputStream.Close();
    m.Close();
}

override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{    
    InitializeComponent();
    base.OnInit(e);
}

private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Page_Load);
}
```

Thanks you in advance,
stev

PS : i already set margin = 0  `Document document = new Document(pageSize, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);`

Comment: did you set label size and margins in printer drivers?

Comment: For about 1 hour i am dealing with this....thanks you.

Comment: so setting in printer drivers helped?

Comment: So add answer, write what you done to fix it and accept answer. Other users with same problem will know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

just set your ZEBRA Configuration

Comment: I have changed the configuration but seems like ZebraNet is not respecting those configuration!

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the `zpl.left_position` SGD command:

E.g.,

```
SGD.SET("zpl.left_position", "0", connection);
```